# Find items that are not duplicates

Tags: google-sheets

I have these cells A1 through A7:

```
Mary 
Susie
Jane
Mary
Susie
Elizabeth
Mary
```

I want to get the names that do not appear multiple times, so my results should be Jane and Elizabeth. I don not want Susie or Mary because they appeared multiple times.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

1. On a copy
2. Insert a blank column on the left
3. Put `=countif(B$1:B$7,B1)` in A1 and copy down to suit
4. Sort A:B
5. Select the names next to `1`, copy and paste where required
6. Delete copy

Answer (score 1):

If you put the following formula in B1:

```
=SORT(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIF(A1:A7, A1:A7)>1,"",A1:A7)))
```

then the result will appear automatically.